# Can every manifold be covered by compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Given a manifold which Hausdorff, second-countable. Does there exist a countable open cover $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ such that the closure $\bar{U_i}$ of each $U_i$ is compact?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with $\Bbb R^n$, and you can cover your manifold with countably many open sets homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. What can you conclude from this?

Comment: It is true that only works on the topological space?